# How to configure the ObjectMapper for Unirest in a spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, unirest

I am using Unirest in a project which is working fine for me.  However, I want to post some data and do not want to escape all the JSON as it looks ugly and is just a pain in the neck.

I found a few links on how to configure the ObjectMapper for Unirest and it gives this code.

```
Unirest.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper() {
        com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper = 
 new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();

        public String writeValue(Object value) {
            try {
                return mapper.writeValueAsString(value);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

        }

        public <T> T readValue(String value, Class<T> valueType) {

            try {
                return mapper.readValue(value, valueType);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

        }
    });
```

But, no examples show where it is best to do this in a Spring Boot API project.

I tried to set it up in the main class method, but I am getting an error that 'setObjectMapper' cannot be resolved.  I also tried to do this in the controller but I get the same error.

My Gradle deps for these two libraries are:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mashape.unirest/unirest-java
compile group: 'com.mashape.unirest', name: 'unirest-java', version: '1.4.5'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.1'
```

Can anyone show me how to use the Jackson object mapper with Unirest in a Spring Boot API project as I have been googling and reading docs for two days now.  Would appreciate some help.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues here:

1. The version of unirest you're using (`1.4.5`) does not contain the feature to configure object mapper. This feature was added later ([github PR](https://github.com/Kong/unirest-java/pull/83)). So you should update to the latest version available at maven central - `1.4.9`. This alone will fix your compilation problem.
2. You can keep your Unirest configuration code in the main method. However if you want to use not default jackson `ObjectMapper()`, but the one from the spring context, then it's better to create something like a fake spring bean to inject ObjectMapper:

```
@Configuration
public class UnirestConfig {

    @Autowired
    private com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        Unirest.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper() {

            public String writeValue(Object value) {
                try {
                    return mapper.writeValueAsString(value);
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            public <T> T readValue(String value, Class<T> valueType) {
                try {
                    return mapper.readValue(value, valueType);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Other than that it looks this library changed the package name. Now it's [com.konghq](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.konghq/unirest-java). You might want to consider updating, but library API might have changed.

Upd: for the latest version

```
compile group: 'com.konghq', name: 'unirest-java', version: '3.1.04'
```

the new API is `Unirest.config().setObjectMapper(...)`

Comment: Thanks for the infos, but there seems to be some version mis-match information.  You say I need the 1.4.9 version but the repository you mention https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.konghq/unirest-java only goes as low as version 2.0.1.  I tried with the latest version from that repository : 3.1.04.  But I still get the same error when I try to use Unirest.setObjectMapper .  'Cannot resolve method setObjectMapper( anonymous kong.unirest.ObjectMapper)  still stuck I am afraid.

Comment: After checking the docs for 3.1.04.  Your code above is almost correct. The configuration has now changed see http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/#configuration.  You just need to alter the above code to 'Unirest.config().setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper()' and mention the new version  I will then mark it as the answer

Comment: Yep, some misunderstanding happened. My answer was for the following dependency: `compile group: 'com.mashape.unirest', name: 'unirest-java', version: '1.4.9'`